# How to get a url map in django?

Tags: python, django

In `flask` I can use `app.url_map` to see all the mapped urls of the app. What is the similar method in `django`? Or how can I know the method to deal with some certain url request?

Comment: @tbicr Not completely solve my question. How can I get the function of the urlpattern? It's better to have a get_view_func(url) return function relate to the urlpattern.

Comment: That is what the [reverse resolution of URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls) is for, the equivalent of `url_for()` in Flask.